# Can I overload an object with a function?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object of functions/values. I'm interested in overloading based on calling behavior.

For example, this block of code below demonstrates what I wish to do.

```
var main_thing = {
    initalized: false,
    something: "Hallo, welt!",
    something_else: [123,456,789],
    load: {
        sub1    : function() {
            //Some stuff
        },
        sub2    : function() {
            //Some stuff
        },
        all     : function() {
            this.sub1();
            this.sub2();
        }
    }
    init: function () {
        this.initalized=true;
        this.something="Hello, world!";
        this.something_else = [0,0,0];
        this.load(); //I want this to call this.load.all() instead.
    }
}
```

The issue to me is that `main_thing.load` is assigned to an object, and to call `main_thing.load.all()` would call the function inside of the object (the `()` operator). What can I do to set up my code so I could use `main_thing.load` as an access the object, and `main_thing.load()` to execute some code? Or at least, similar behavior.

Basically, this would be similar to a default constructor in other languages where you don't need to call main_thing.constructor().

If this isn't possible, please explain with a bit of detail.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a constructor, but you've described it as overloading.  I don't see any function overloading here.

Comment: Functions are objects, so you could also set "subfunctions" as properties of a function. Btw `this` in `main_thing.load.all` does not refer to `main_thing` but to `main_thing.load`.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding - but what if you add a var loadfunctions = { sub1 : function() { .. }, sub2 ... }, then write rewrite your load to something like load: function(switch) { if (!switch) { loadfunctions.all; } else ... etc

Comment: @Ned it doesn't always need to be a constructor, just a function that is called. Constructors are called on object construction. This is similar to it but not quite the same as it isn't related to construction.

Comment: @Felix Thanks for spotting that,. @Prescott I'm not sure I understand what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Tom Tu said, functions are objects, and can have properties...

```
var main_thing = {

    // load will be set to the result of this anonymous function
    // which is a function with 2 extra properties set for the other functions        
    load: function() {
        // create what will be the load() function and store in "all"
        var all = function () {

               // When the function is actually executed these will have been assigned
               all.load1();
               all.load2();
            };

        // set 2 properties for sub load functions
        all.load1 = function() {};
        all.load2 = function() {};

        // return our function
        return all;
    }()
}

main_thing.load();
// or 
main_thing.load.load1();
main_thing.load.load2();
```

Comment: +1 Had this as my second attempt. This is I believe the closest thing you can get to solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

Because function objects are just objects, there's no real distinction between an object property that refers to a function versus one that refers to a plain object. Thus, "load" is just a property of the outer object.

What you could do is initialize the "load" object inside your "init" function such that its functions have access to the outer object reference via a closure:

```
init: function() {
  // whatever ...

  var main_thing = this;
  this.load.sub1 = function() {
    main_thing.foo = "bar";
  };
  this.load.sub2 = function() {
    main_thing.somethingElse();
  }
}
```

Now those functions in the "load" sub-object have access to that "main_thing" local variable, which will refer to the outer object. It won't matter how they're invoked.

Another approach would be to use the "bind()" facility in newer browsers or as provided by a library like Prototype of Functional. (Personally I just steal bind from Functional.js because it's a nice clean implementation.):

```
init: function() {
  // ...

  this.load.sub1 = function() {
    this.foo = "bar";
  } .bind(this);

}
```

That approach ensures that no matter how "sub1" is called, it'll always have `this` bound to the reference to the outer object that was available when it ("sub1", that is) was defined.

Comment: not addressing the problem at all. He wants to getters. he wants Foo.a to be dealt with as data and Foo.a() to be dealt with as a function

Comment: That might possibly work, @Raynos, but I haven't messed with any ES5 code (or the equivalent facilities in Mozilla JavaScript). Write up an answer like that and I'll upvote it :-)

Comment: Also, @Raynos, I think it does address at least some of the OP concerns: he wants to call `main_thing.load.sub1()` but have `this` be bound to `main_thing` and not `main_thing.load`.

Comment: what I mentioned isn't possible without compiler your JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload javascript quite like that.
If you make main_thing.load a function, then you can call main_thing.load(), and you can also access internal values, like so:

```
main_thing.load.a = 7;
main_thing.load.b = "text";
main_thing.load.foo = function(x,y){alert("Hello, world "+x+", "+y); };
main_thing.load.foo(main_thing.load.a,main_thing.load.b);
```

which alerts "Hello, world 7 text".

But main_thing.load itself can either be used to store a function, or to store some other data, but not both.