# Default function on an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Is it possible to set a default function on an object, such that when I call `myObj()` that function is executed? Let's say I have the following `func` object

```
function func(_func) {
    this._func = _func;

    this.call = function() {
        alert("called a function");
        this._func();
    }
}

var test = new func(function() {
    // do something
});

test.call();
```

​I'd like to replace `test.call()` with simply `test()`. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I overload an object with a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946794/can-i-overload-an-object-with-a-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

return a function:

```
function func(_func) {
    this._func = _func;

    return function() {
        alert("called a function");
        this._func();
    }
}

var test = new func(function() {
    // do something
});

test();
```

but then `this` refers to the *returned function (right?) or window*, you will have to cache `this` to access it from inside the function (`this._func();`)

```
function func(_func) {
    var that = this;

    this._func = _func;

    return function() {
        alert("called a function");
        that._func();
    }
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot. Just for hoots, here's how I wound up using this: http://jsfiddle.net/TkZ6d/9/ Thanks again!